# Remove append and change serial no in jquery append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

I have a JQuery append function to add question answer(multiple choice).

If I append four answers as Option 1,Option 2,Option 3,Option 4,and remove Option 2 means I want that all the other 3 answers have to be in order like Option 1, Option 2,Option 3.

```
$('.more_answer'+id+'').append('
    <div class="col-md-8" >
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Option '+a+' </label>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <span class="ans_btns">
               <input type="radio" name="answer'+id+'" value='+a+' id="answer'+id+a+'" class="css-checkbox more_answer'+id+'answer'+a+'"" />
               <label for="answer'+id+a+'" class="css-label radGroup1">
           </span>
       </label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control fc-inline-md">
       <a href="javascript::" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" class="remove_this btn btn-danger btn-sm" >Remove</a>
       </div>
   </div>');
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: if i remove an one appened element in the middil means i want all others should be in a order. (1,2,3,..)

Comment: Can you share some more code, like the whole function and the HTML that belongs to it...

Comment: A simple way to do it is to just clear the children from your `'.more_answer'+id+''` element then add the remaining `<div class="col-md-8" >` elements back in order.